# geting no result from GetStringUTFChars JNI

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

android NDK for my android application. i am stuck on the starting lines and it is not compiling further. Following is my code. It doest not compile after **"str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename, NULL);"**. Please check my java and c code

The java code:

```
public class MyffmpegActivity extends Activity {

private static native int logFileInfo(String filename);

static
{
    Log.i("HEHA", "HOHA");
    System.loadLibrary("mylib");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myffmpeg);
    String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    path=path+"/test.mp4";
    Log.i("Name Returned is ", ":"+path);
int x=logFileInfo(path);


}
```

The C code

```
jint Java_com_example_myffmpegtest_MyffmpegActivity_logFileInfo(JNIEnv * env, jobject  this, jstring filename)
{

av_register_all();
   AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
   const jbyte *str;

  str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename, NULL);
 if(av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, str, NULL, 0, NULL)!=0)
 {
    LOGE("Can't open file '%s'\n", str);
    return 1;
}
else
{

    LOGI("File was opened\n");
    LOGI("File '%s', Codec %s",
        pFormatCtx->filename,
        pFormatCtx->iformat->name
    );
}
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use jbyte? Have you tried 
`const char * str =(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename, NULL);`  yet?

EDIT:
If you are sure that filename is not null, the problem maybe comes from av_open_input_file function call below it. FFmpeg use file protocol to open input file, that means you need to make the file name look like this "file:///.../test.mp4"

hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
const char *str;
str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename, NULL);
```

Also, it looks like you are trying to develop something I already created a solution for. Check out [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever).

Comment: Sorry there was no issue with the syntax but some mistake in Android.mk file